# How to separate a string in java using multiple delimiters and with no white space available?

Tags: java, lexer

how can i separate a string like this in java? 
Quotes are not seperate. The following code is entirely a string along with println. And i need to separate it into tokens as in the output.

```
println "How are you",Sir, "Hope you are doing good","?"
```

Note: There are no whitespaces between you" and , and so on..
output:

```
println
"how are you"
,
Sir
,
"Hope you are doing good"
,
"?"
```

Comment: you want replacement or split? as i can see in your ouput part it seems to be a replacement of `,` with `<whitespace> ,`

Comment: its split.. basically i need to split the entire string into tokens. And in many places like `How are you` and `,` there is no whitespace.

Comment: Do you need to include the delimiters in the output?  I.e., do you have to print out the quotes and the comma?

Comment: yes @markspace. Quotes and commas are needed.

Comment: @user5515512 hopefully you will get the required result with my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know if it is optimised but it will give your desired results.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\"[^\"]*\")|(\\w+)|(,)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        while(matcher.find()){
            if(matcher.group(2)!=null)
            System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
            if(matcher.group(1)!=null)
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            if(matcher.group(3)!=null)
            System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
        }
```

Comment: Works Perfect! Thanks. I guess i need to take a deep dive into Regex and pattern class. I have many more conditions to cover. Any suggestion where i can look to learn about the both?

Comment: [http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html),
[http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm),[https://regexone.com/](https://regexone.com/),

Refer this and there are many more which you can refer.

Comment: If you have "many more" conditions to cover, I'd recommend hand rolling a parser.  It's not hard, and the regex will get insanely complicated, or might even be impossible.

Comment: @markspace Yes i went over the idea of making a parser by myself. Thanks. I might need to start somewhere. Any suggestions/resources available?